# How to delete an ActiveRecord in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a quick question. I have a model that I gotta get rid off. I have tried something like the following, but I get an error called `Call to a member function delete() on array`:

This is what I have tried so far.

```
$foundTeams = UserHasTeam::find()->where(['user_has_team.user_iduser' => $model->id])->all();
$foundTeams->delete();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is static method `deleteAll()` for this in **ActiveRecord**.

```
UserHasTeam::deleteAll(['user_iduser' => $model->id]);
```

This will delete all rows from UserHasTeam::tableName() where `user_iduser` is `$model->id`.